# Integration-finding an upper limit of integration.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm given the value of an integral: $$\int_1^a (x-\frac{w^3}{x^2})\,dx=1.5$$ and told that the total area between the graph of $$y=x-\frac{w^3}{x^2}$$ and the x-axis is 6.5 units squared. w and a are both integers greater than 1. How can I find the values of w and a?

Comment: Hint: 

Find an antiderivative for the function $f(x)=x-\frac{w^3}{x^2}$ and then use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @mrsamy I have tried this, but I'm still stuck. I know that the integral from 1 to some value z (where z is greater than or equal to a and w) of our function y is 6.5, and so, the integral from a to z of the function y should be 5. Whenever I use the fundamental theorem of calculus I'm left with either an equation with 2 unknowns or 3 unknowns. If you could show me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no region bounded by the graph of the function and the $x$-axis.

Comment: By "total area" do you mean the integral between $1$ and $a$ of the absolute value of the function?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, total area as in the integral between 1 and the value the function is defined for, which I have assumed is the value z, as we are not told, where z is a value greater than or equal to 2. I'm assuming this because we are told that a and w are both integers greater than 1, so the function must be defined on the domain [1,z].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x-\frac{w^3}{x^2}$.

We know that the function is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and that it has $x$-intercept $(w,0)$. So we have

$$ \int_1^w f(x)\,dx+\int_w^a f(x)\,dx=1.5\tag{1} $$

$$ -\int_1^w f(x)\,dx+\int_w^a f(x)\,dx=6.5\tag{2} $$

Would you like me to work it further or do you see how to proceed?

Here is the next step:

Subtract equation (2) from equation (1) and divide by 2 to get

$$ \int_1^w f(x)\,dx =-2.5\tag{3} $$

but you can also find the value of the integral directly

$$ \int_1^w f(x)\,dx =-w^3+\frac{3}{2}w^2-\frac{1}{2}\tag{4} $$

giving

$$ 2w^3-3w^2-4=0 $$

which has a real solution $w=2$.

Now if you add equations (1) and (2) and divide by $2$ you will get

$$ \int_2^a f(x)\,dx=4 $$

If you evaluate this integral directly you will get an equation which you can solve for $a$, which is also an integer.

[image: Diagram of areas]

Comment: Thank you everyone, this helps a lot. I understand that the function is increasing for the set of positive real numbers. However, our teacher didn't give us a graph of the function. With this in mind, how do we know that the curve is below the x-axis for x-values between 1 and w? Also, in constructing your equations 1 and 2, you have assumed 1<w<a, how do we know that w<a? Also, how do we know that the area of 6.5 units squared, is for the region covered between 1 and a? Sorry if these questions are obvious.

Comment: I removed the assumption $1<w<a$ because it is unnecessary. Equations (1) and (2) are true regardless of the relative relationship of $1, w$ and $a$. We find out the values of $w$ and $a$ after solving the equations. And since we know that the function is increasing and that $f(w)=0$ we know that $f(x)<0$ on the interval $1<x<w$ and that $f(x)>0$ when $x>w$. And $6.5$ is the geometrical area of the two regions whereas $1.5$ is the integral because the area to the left of $w$  is subtracted from the area to the right.

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_1^a \left(x-\frac{w^3}{x^2}\right) \, dx=\left[\frac{w^3}{x}+\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_1^a=\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{a}-w^3-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}$$
The second condition is unclear. The graph of the family of functions $$y=x-\frac{w^3}{x^2}$$
is like the one in the image below. There is no finite area.

When OP will tell what is the area we are talking about I'll try to help further.

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Our teacher only said that the total area between the graph of y=f(x) and the x-axis is 6.5 units squared. That's all we were told. So that area of 6.5, I don't know what x values that's defined between.

Comment: @nd37 It looks like this problem is not well posed. Can you ask your teacher where is defined the second integral? Because if we knew this, we had two simultaneous equations in $a,w$ and try to solve